# Validating Image Uploads

Tags: laravel-5

Yo! I am working on a form where I attach some image.

Form:

```
{{ Form::file('attachments[]', array('multiple')) }}
```

Validation:

```
$this->validate($response, array(
    'attachments' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
));
```

I have also tried 'image' as validator rule but whenever I post the form with jpg image I get back errors:

> The attachments must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.

Working with Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined an input name of `attachments[]`, attachments will be an array **containing** your file. If you only need to upload one file, you might want to rename your input name to be `attachments`, without the `[]` (or `attachment` would make more sense in that case). If you need to be able to upload multiple, you can build an iterator inside your `Request`-extending class that returns a set of rules covering each entry inside `attachments[]`

```
protected function attachments()
{
    $rules          = [];
    $postedValues   = $this->request->get('attachments');

    if(null == $postedValues) {
        return $rules;
    }

    // Let's create some rules!
    foreach($postedValues as $index => $value) {
        $rules["attachments.$index"] = 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png';
    }
    /* Let's imagine we've uploaded 2 images. $rules would look like this:
        [
            'attachments.0' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
            'attachments.1' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
        ];
    */

    return $rules;
}
```

Then, you can just call that function inside `rules()` to merge the array returned from `attachments` with any other rules you might want to specify for that request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array_merge($this->attachments(), [
       // Create any additional rules for your request here... 
    ]);
}
```

If you do not yet have a dedicated `Request`-extending class for your form, you can [create one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) with the artisan cli by entering: `php artisan make:request MyRequestName`. A new request class will be created inside `app\Http\Requests`. That is the file where you would put the code above in. Next, you may just [typehint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#accessing-the-request) this class inside the function signature of your controller endpoint:

```
public function myControllerEndpoint(MyRequestName $request)
{
    // Do your logic... (if your code gets here, all rules inside MyRequestName are met, yay!)
}
```